# How to script changing to a difference user and then running command with their sudo permissions -MacOS

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Whenever I reboot my macbook, the bluetooth USB doesn't work until I run:

```
sudo pkill bluetoothd
```

I'm trying to make user Automator to run an AppleScript, so my SO can click on an icon on the desktop and this will run without them having to drop into the shell.

This computer auto-logs into a restricted account so I first need to change users to somebody with sudo privelages, so that sequence becomes this:

```
media@computer ~ % su - root_account
Password:

root_account@computer ~ % sudo pkill bluetoothd
Password:
```

I have attempted:

```
su - root_account && sudo pkill bluetoothd
```

but that just logs onto the root_account and stop there.

I found the following vid guide for how to get it to prompt for the sudo password interactively by defining the following script:

```
do shell script "your commands" with administrator privileges
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to write the command now

https://www.dognmonkey.com/techs/how-to-create-macos-app-to-run-sudo-command-with-password.html

Comment: I assume your main user doesn't have admin privileges?

Comment: [Technical Note TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-HOW_DO_I_GET_ADMINISTRATOR_PRIVILEGES_FOR_A_COMMAND_)

Comment: @nohillside no, the "media" user is not privileged. This is a publicly accessible HTPC setup.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the computer?

Comment: Re `su - root_account && sudo pkill bluetoothd` stopping after logging in as root... yes, even if `su` allowed you to pass a command line, which it doesn't, the invocation of `sudo pkill bluetoothd` is happening in the original shell, conditioned by the return code of the `su` invocation.

Comment: `sudo` can be configured to allow non-admin users to run priviledged commands. Does the directory `/etc/sudoers.d` exist on your Mac?

Comment: Your command can not work : && means that the second command execute if the first succeed. && means that if you can execute command before , the command after will execute in the same environment not in «su - » environnement. BTW, Unix does not enable su/ssh to run sudo .